# In react I have JQuery npm and I have used JQuery in my chart-custom.js file but still getting jQuery undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, web-applications

**but still getting a jQuery undefined error while chart-custom.js file appending.**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import $ from 'jquery';

class Dashboard extends Component {
 componentDidMount(){
    const jQuery = $;
    console.log(jQuery); //JQuery working fine.

    //for safer side I have also used local jquery 
    let alpha = document.createElement("script");
    alpha.src = require('../assets/js/jquery.min.js');
    alpha.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(alpha);

    let script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = require('../assets/js/chart-custom.js'); //error In this line
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
```

Comment: The "src" attribute of a script should be a string URL.

Comment: src is taking this attribute no problem in that @Pointy

Comment: Well yes, but it's wrong. And if there were "no problem" you would not have posted the question.,

Comment: @Pointy If It does not use require function It cannot find the chat-custom.js. Do you have any other good way to import local customized js files in react?

Comment: `require()` loads a script. If you've loaded the script, why would you have to load it *again* via a `<script>` tag?

Comment: @Pointy not like that, I used require function to find the resource in the project. without require function, I am getting 404 file not found.